# Nagios : CPUUtilization UNKNOWN - failed to retrieve data. check arguments

Tags: amazon-web-services, nagios, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-rds

I am using the script to monitor my RDS. When I tried I got this error:
CPUUtilization UNKNOWN - failed to retrieve data. check arguments.

I can get the response from command line:
/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_cloudwatch us-east-1 CPUUtilization "Average" "AWS/RDS" "DBInstanceIdentifier=rds-test" 360 60 80

CPUUtilization OK - 7.692 Percent

but it does not work with nagios... who can help me?? Much appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Upon research I found that I need to set the PATH for the Nagios user. But I tried to do this. Could anyone help me the right way to set the PATH for Nagios user if its the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which script you are using, but you should test it as run by the nagios user:

```
sudo -u nagios /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_cloudwatch us-east-1 CPUUtilization "Average" "AWS/RDS" "DBInstanceIdentifier=rds-test" 360 60 80
```

This should give the same error message as you have in nagios and help you fix your problem.

I imagine that the script cannot connect to AWS.
I use the following script (https://github.com/FastSociety/nagios-cloudwatch-plugin/blob/master/check_cloudwatch.py) which uses boto which itself is configured in /etc/boto.cfg (at least on Ubuntu), so this might be an alternative for you as well.